# Why does this 'generic' Rust code doesn't work as expected?

Tags: rust, traits

I've recently taken on learning Rust and I'm trying to write a small expression evaluator. I've been practicing Rust for a few days now and thought this task would be cool to work with Rust's Traits. What I tried to do is make Sum & Number structs implement Expression trait, so that I could express (pun unintended) **(1 + 2)** as an *expression* where left and right hand sides are expressions too. 
I've stumbled onto the problem that you can't just use Traits as properties' types, so you instead should use *&dyn Trait* or *Box* in the Book. Following this notion a rewrote it and now it compiles, but I can't get access to values inside Sum. 
Here's my code:

```
trait Expression {}
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Number {
    pub val: i32
}

impl Expression for Number {}

struct Sum {
    pub left: Box<dyn Expression>,
    pub right: Box<dyn Expression>
}

impl Expression for Sum {}

fn main() {
    let e = Sum{ left: Box::new(Number{ val: 2}),
                 right: Box::new(Number{ val: 2})
    };
    let sum = (2 + 2);
    println!("{:#?}", sum);
}
```

What I want to be able to do is get to *Number*'s value:

```
e.left.val
```

and use nested constuctions like:

```
Sum{Sum{Number, Sum{Number, Number}}, Number}
```

I also tried to make explicit cast to Number:

```
let val = (e.left as Number).val;
```

But it fails with an error:
**non-primitive cast: `std::boxed::Box<(dyn Expression + 'static)>` as `Number`**
**note: an `as` expression can only be used to convert between primitive types. Consider using the `From` trait**.

Sorry for any language mistakes or messy explanation, English is not my first language.
I'm not an experienced programmer and very new to Rust so I would really appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: Bottom line, Rust doesn't let you "cast" non-primitive types. You'll need to either implement the `From` trait, as mentioned by the compiler, or use [`Box::downcast`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.downcast) to _attempt_ to extract a `Number` from a `Box<dyn Expression`.

Comment: @Brian I'm trying to implement ```From``` trait right now and still dont understand how to extract ```Number``` that lies in ```Box<dyn Expression>``` to construct new ```Number```. My code for this is: 
`
impl From<Box<dyn Expression>> for Number {
    fn from(expr: Box<dyn Expression>) -> Self {
        //?
Number {
            val: expr.
        }
    }
}
`

Comment: `From` only makes sense if  _every_ `Expression` can be converted to a Number. Is this true for your design? Bear in mind, there is nothing stopping you from implementing `Expression` for, say, `Vec`. All your `From` implementation knows is that `expr` is an `Expression` trait object, which could be _any_ type. Traits may be the wrong abstraction for what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: You should add a `fn value (&self) -> i32` method to your `Expression` trait, then implement the proper behaviour for `Sum` and `Number`.

Comment: @Jmb yes, that worked, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Rust doesn't let you cast non primitive types.

Reference:
https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/types/cast.html

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to do is this ([complete code in the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=363abecf27b47788023c6f1e1696ab31)):

```
trait Expression {
    fn evaluate(&self) -> i32;
}

impl Expression for Number {
    fn evaluate(&self) -> i32 {
        self.val
    }
}

impl Expression for Sum {
    fn evaluate(&self) -> i32 {
        self.left.evaluate() + self.right.evaluate()
    }
}
```